# What does document.forms mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms

In JavaScript, what is the meaning of the identifiers `document.forms` and the `.value` field?

I have trouble understanding the use of the below syntax example.

```
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value
```

Comment: I am confused. Do you want to know about document.cookie or document.forms?

Comment: @the_draw i want to know .value property and document.form function

Comment: document.forms is not a function. It's an hash table. In fact everything in javascript is a hash table but document.forms is meant to be used as a hash table. And for the love of god improve your English. People need to understand you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value`

that will get the `value` of the "email" element within the "myForm" `<form>`

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <input id="email" name="email" value="some@email.com" />
</form>
```

so `x` will equal "some@email.com"

---

`document.forms` will return a collection of all of the forms within a particular page. writing `document.forms["myForm"]` will return the form with the name "myForm" from that collection

Comment: you had explain the .value property, how about the document.form? Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

`documents.forms` is an object containing all of the forms for that HTML document. With this code, you are referencing the elements by their `name` attributes (not `id`). So this would provide a string containing the `value` for the form element with the `name` "email" within the `form` with the `name` "myForm".

Example:

```
<form name="contact-form">
Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
</form>
```

Executing the following JavaScript code at anytime when a value for the email field is desired would provide the value.

```
var contact_email = document.forms["contact-form"]["email"].value;
```

The `contact_email` variable would then contain the value entered into the `input` field.

Answer (score 0):

```
this code shows how you can use document.forms in an example with validation.
```

``

```
        function validation(inputs){
            if (inputs==""|| inputs=="null"){
            alert("Enter Valid Number");
            return false;
        }
            if (isNaN(inputs)){
            alert("Enter Valid Number");
            return false;
        }
            return true;
        }


        function triNum(num){
            var triangle=0;
            for(i=1 ;i <= num; i++){
                triangle += i;
            }
            return triangle;
        }

        function squareNum(num){
            var square = num * num;
            return square;
        }


        function findNums(){
            //var num = document.getElementById('number1').value;
            var num= document.forms["MagicNum"]["FirstNum"].value;
            if (validation(num)){
                document.forms["MagicNum"]["tri"].value=triNum(num);
                document.forms["MagicNum"]["square"].value=squareNum(num);
            }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.forms` returns a collection of all forms in an actual `document`. To access all forms in iframes, frames and windows from actual `document` you have to switch to correct `document` from them.

You have 3 possible ways to access elements:

1. Over array like method:

```js
function setEmail()
{
    document.forms['myForm']['email'].value = 'new@example.com';
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
    <input name="email"/>
</form>
<button onclick="setEmail()">Set email Adresse</button>
```

2. Over variables:

```js
function setEmail()
{
    document.forms.myForm.email.value = 'new@example.com';
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
    <input name="email"/>
</form>
<button onclick="setEmail()">Set email Adresse</button>
```

3. Over combined way – using array like way + variables. It is in the case if the name from form field has some symbols which are not allowed by variable names. For example `my-form`.

```js
function setEmail()
{
    document.forms['my-form'].email.value = 'new@example.com';
}
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
    <input name="email"/>
</form>
<button onclick="setEmail()">Set email Adresse</button>
```